# Get browser popup blocker status using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, popup-blocker

To end a user´s browsersession successfully on browser-unload we need to open a new window to call some webservice to reset the user´s session data on the server.
With an active popup blocker this will not succeed.

Our solution is querying the popupblocker-status when starting our application, stop further execution when the blocker is turned on, and request the user to turn off popup-blocking, or at least make him/her accept popups from our application/url or not....

I have read a lot on how to determine if a popup is being blocked. All examples are using window.open which actually opens a window if the blocker appears to be off. 
We would like to avoid this window to appear (and close it right away), just to check if the blocker is turned on.

Do you happen to know if there is an alternative way to get a browser´s popupblocker-status?
By reading a browser-property for example?

Comment: Why don't you just send out an AJAX request or reload the current page instead?

Comment: I have been experimenting with sending an AJAX request while the page is being unloaded. However, it oftens happens that the page is unloaded before it can execute the AJAX call. Reloading the page is not a logical step I think, when a user decides to close the page to just reopen the page again.